# Help required: please evaluate the two given integrals

Tags: integration

Question:

Evaluate the following integral.

[image]

My answer:

$=\displaystyle\cos (6t)+6t . 7t/7 = -\cos(6 . \pi/2) + (6\pi)/2 . (7.(\pi/2)) /7$

Correct answer:

$\frac{2}{3}.$

While you are at it could you also answer this one as well

[image]

(sorry I did not know how to write the equations in proper form here!)

Comment: Have you learnt integration by substitution? In that case, put in $u = 3t$ for the first integral, and do something similar for the second.

Comment: is -2/3 . cos (3pi/s) correct answer for the first one?

Comment: your pictures are awesome! Question: which is the function (up to a constant) whose derivative is equal to $\sin(3t)?$

Comment: oh thanks :) I already solve that one! the one above is totally wrong. Now I'm doing the second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{-1}{3}\cos(3t) \right) = \sin(3t)$.

Comment: is -2/3 . cos (3pi/s) correct answer for the first one?

Comment: The correct answer is $\frac{2}{3}$ since $\cos(0) = 1$ and $\cos(3\pi/2) = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

hopefully this is the correct way of doing it. The answer matches the one given in the book!

[image]

Comment: $$\int f(t)dt = \int( \sin(2t)-\cos(2t) )dt = \frac{-\cos(2t) - \sin(2t)}{2} = F(t)$$ and $$\int_a^b f(t)dt = F(b) - F(a)$$ by Newton-Leibniz Theorem.